# wget failure in docker on windows

Tags: windows, docker, nuget, wget, docker-build

I am new to docker. I am trying to build a simple web app which needs to access a private Nuget feed.When I ran "docker build", I get the following error: 'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The command 'cmd /S /C wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash' returned a non-zero code: 255

Here's my Dockerfile:

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build 
 
WORKDIR /app 
ARG PAT 
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash
... ...

Running the command:
docker build -t app:1.0 --build-arg PAT=value .

I've installed wget and added it to PATH.

Windows version: 10.0.19041.208 & Docker version: 19.03.8

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need to install `wget` _within the container_, before `RUN wget` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please share how to do that? apt-get command didn't work either.